# Angular en-AU locale not working for currency pipe

Tags: angular

I'm adding the following code in my app.module in order to set en-AU locale as default:

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeAu from '@angular/common/locales/en-AU';

registerLocaleData(localeAu);

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-AU' },
  ],
})
```

I've injected it into my component:

```
fee = 20.0

constructor(
  @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string) {

}
```

When I try to view the locale in my component:

```
<h1>Current locale: {{ locale }}</h1>
<h1>Fee default: {{ fee | currency }}</h1>
<h1>Fee AUD: {{ fee | currency:'AUD' }}</h1>
```

I see the following:

```
Current locale: en-AU
Fee default: USD20.00
Fee AUD: $20.00
```

Why is the default fee not $20.00?

Comment: Can you replicate this in satckblitz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found something very strange:

As per the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#parameters) default value for `display` property in `Currency` pipe is `symbol` which for some strange reason is 'AUD'. If you want to display **$** sign change your code to:

```
<h1>Fee AUD: {{ amount | currency:null:'symbol-narrow' }}</h1>
```

Now for the strange part, I have created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjk2pc) for demonstration. It has same problem as you described. However, if I change my code from

```
registerLocaleData(localeAu);
```

to

```
registerLocaleData(localeAu, 'AU');
```

code works fine and symbol *USD* is replaces with *$*.

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me crazy!